# Accessing multiple tables at the same time and multiplying values in SQL

Tags: mysql

My problem is very specific and I couldn't figure out a better name for the title.

I have 3 tables, which are `Pessoa (Person)`, `Bicicleta (Bicicle)` and `Viagem (Trip)`:

[image]

What I want to do is select the names of the individuals by alphabetic order who had a trip, together with the `Avaliacao (Evaluation)` multiplied by `Valor_Viagem (Trip cost)`.

What I tried to do (not working properly nor finished):

```
select distinct PESSOA.Nome, VIAGEM.Avaliacao, VIAGEM.Id_Bicicleta, BICICLETA.Valor_Viagem from PESSOA, VIAGEM
    join BICICLETA ON VIAGEM.Id_Bicicleta = BICICLETA.Id where PESSOA.Email IN (
        SELECT Email_Utilizador FROM VIAGEM
        );
```

Which gives me:

[image]

^This is NOT what I want, as stated before.

Comment: Can you show us what you want the results to look like?  I'm not 100% clear from your question commentary what the output should actually be.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not 100% sure what you are looking for, but I assume you need a list of distinct names that contains the Avalacao * Valor_Viagem summed for each person (so a person with 5 trips has five times Avalacao * Valor_Viagem + ... + ...).

That is very easy to achieve:

```
select PESSOA.Nome, VIAGEM.Avaliacao, VIAGEM.Id_Bicicleta, BICICLETA.Valor_Viagem from PESSOA, VIAGEM, SUM(VIAGEM.Avaliacao * BICICLETA.Valor_viagem)  AS trip_cost
join BICICLETA ON VIAGEM.Id_Bicicleta = BICICLETA.Id where PESSOA.Email IN (
    SELECT Email_Utilizador FROM VIAGEM
    ) GROUP BY PESSOA.Nome;
```

**What happens is the following:**

- first you compute the product for each trip
- than you use the GROUP BY clause to group persons with identical names together
- using SUM in combination with GROUP BY causes to sum all values of persons within this group, in that case all records with the same PESSOA.Nome

**A word of warning**

This assumes you will have distinct names. This appears risky. Better assign each person a unique Id and use this Id as foreign key instead of the name.